# Are Google Analytics Management API ids constant?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to access data about particular website thru Google Analytics API. Currently I request many ids before I actually request the data I need:

```
accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()
firstAccountId = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id') # returns 45112345
webproperties = service.management().webproperties().list(accountId=firstAccountId).execute()
firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.get('items')[0].get('id') # returns UA-45112345-1
profiles = service.management().profiles().list(accountId=firstAccountId,webPropertyId=firstWebpropertyId).execute()
profile_id = profiles.get('items')[0].get('id') # returns 78212345
```

Do I really need to request this ids each time I work with Google Analytics API?
Or, can I just hardcode them? Can I hardcode `profile id` 78212345?

**Upd**. looking at [the doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/#user_reports), seems they could be hardcoded.

Comment: I need some more information to help:  Which language are you using? Are you using the client lib for that language (looks like it)?  Do you need to know the information from the management API or do you just want to request data from the core reporting API for a static profile id?  Also check https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountSummariesGuide

Comment: @DaImTo, the language is Python/GAE. I use Google API Python Client (GAE-version). I am going to use core reporting API only.

Comment: Then you don't need to go though the management API at all you should be able to just supply your profileid. I don't know python but let me see if I can find some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no python expert but:  [Tutorial: Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api)

```
def get_results(service, profile_id):
# Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
return service.data().ga().get(
  ids='ga:' + profile_id,
  start_date='2012-03-03',
  end_date='2012-03-03',
  metrics='ga:visits').execute()
```

The profile id has to start with a ga: so you should just be able to add your profile id there.  You still need to be authenticated but you don't need to go though the Management API to get the profile information.

Oh and after spying on your old question: This should still work even though you are using a service account its the same your still authenticated.  ( sorry for spying )

Hope this helps.